# Should I use a nestjs pipe, guard or I should go for an interceptor?

Tags: nestjs

Well I have a few pipes in the application I'm working on and I'm starting to think they actually should be guards or even interceptors.

One of them is called `PincodeStatusValidationPipe` and its job as simple as snow. It checks the cache for a certain value if that value is the one expected then it returns what it gets otherwise it throws the FORBIDEN exception.

Another `pipe` is called `UserExistenceValidationPipe` it operates on the `login` method and checks if a user exists in DB and some other things related to that user (e.g. wheter a password expected in the login method is present and if it does then whether it matches that of the retrieved user) otherwise it throws appropriate exceptions.

I know it's more of a design question but I find it quite important and I would appreciate any hints. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Well I think `UserExistenceValidationPipe` is definitely not the best name choice, something like `UserValidationPipe` fits way better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are throwing a `FORBIDEN` already, I would suggest migrating the `PincodeStatusValidationPipe` to be `PincodeStatusValidationGuard`, as returning `false` from a guard will throw a `FORBIDEN` for you. You'll also have full access to the Request object which is pretty nice to have.

For the `UserExistenceValidationPipe`, a pipe is not the worst thing to have. I consider existence validation to be a part of business logic, and as such should be handled in the service, but that's me. I use pipes for data validation and transformation, meaning I check the shape of the data there and pass it on to the service if the shape *looks* correct.

As for interceptors, I like to use those for logging, caching, and response mapping, though I've heard of others using interceptors for overall validators instead of using multiple pipes.

---

As the question is mostly an opinionated one, I'll leave the final decision up to you. In short, guards are great for short circuiting requests with a failure, interceptors are good for logging, caching, and response mapping, and pipes are for data validation and transformation.

Comment: Great reply! Thank you.

Comment: @Jay McDoniel, I'm a bit confused then about this section of the docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#transformation-use-case, i.e. last part about `UserByIdPipe` is kinda close to the `UserExistenceValidationPipe` in this thread, right ?

Comment: @A.Maitre that would be correct. A pipe that gets the user from the database. As  I said in my answer, _I_ consider data existence to be a part of the business logic and it goes in the service, **but** you absolutely can use a pipe if that's what you want